# Do we know definitively in what order were the letters of James, Peter, John and Jude written?

Tags: new-testament, 1-john, 1-peter, book-of-james, jude

In the New Testament, in addition to the four Gospels of Matthew, Mark, Luke and John, The Acts of the Apostles, and the Epistles written by Paul, there are other letters (epistles) written by James, Peter, John and Jude. Do we know definitively in what order these letters were written?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: From internal evidence (timing of the diaspora ; Paul's imprisonments ; John's exile) it is fairly clear what the order is. However those who wish to cast doubt upon authorship have propagated a different scheme. I think you will need to scope this question towards a particular Christian group. Or request a survey of all possible views.